# Splitter Controls for VB 6.0

Tags: vb6, splitter

I need a good splitter control for my project. Does any one have one?

Answer (score 3):

There's a good article on creating yourself a splitter here:

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5367667.html

It's not too difficult to do, so you shouldn't need to "buy a control".

Comment: It is usually easier to build a splitter inline (within a Form) than to develop a general purpose container-style UserControl.  I have one I'm working on but the little things can eat you alive.