# Splitter control for VB6

Tags: vb6

This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334435/splitter-controls-for-vb-6-0), and I've actually [answered it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334435/splitter-controls-for-vb-6-0/1338063#1338063).

But I need a somewhat more sophisticated splitter control.  I need to have a grippie like this

[image: this].  In addition, I need a grippie mode where the contents are collapsed.

[image: collapsed.]

Either a commercial or a freebie control will suffice.

Comment: try implementing own component using frames could be another option

Comment: We use SizerOne, there is a free trial. http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/SizerOne/

Comment: @jac SizerOne doesn't seem to do what I outlined above.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had to get back to work to look at it. My bad, The last version we used was 6 and I thought I remembered the control having the grippie you were after.